# Activerecord: reorder item and insert at position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table with some records (about 20 records).

I need to manage the order of this table so I added a "position" field.

Do you know if is there any gem ready?

I know [Act as List](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) but it needs a data model like this:

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todo_items, -> { order(position: :asc) }
end

class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todo_list
  acts_as_list scope: :todo_list
end
```

My data model is

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :content_share
end

class ContentShare < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feed
end
```

ContentShare is a huge table so I don't want to manage position in that table but directly in the feed, that has only 20 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to go looking for gems is https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/ - there are categories for just about everything, including [sortable active record models](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Sortables)